# Rails Navigation Partial Seeing Universal Variable from some Views but Not Others

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a shopping cart button in the `_navbar.html.erb` partial of my app (rendered in my `application.html.erb` layout) that uses the variable `@current_order`.

My `application_controller.rb` defines `@current_order`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_order
 
  private
 
  def set_order
    @current_order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @current_order = Order.create!
    session[:order_id] = @current_order.id
    @current_order
  end

end
```

The navbar looks like this:

```
 ...
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-invisible position-relative">
        <%= simple_form_for(@current_order, html: { id: "goToCart" }) do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :move_to_checkout, value: false %>
          <%= button_tag( :class => "btn-invisible mt-2") do %>
            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        
        <span class="position-absolute translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
          <%= @current_order.order_number_of_items %>
        </span>
      </button>
    </li>
 ...
```

On my empty `root` page, it renders just fine, but on pages that deal with an `@order` or with `@current_order`, I get an error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass
```

This is called on the `simple_form_for(@current_order)` line of the navbar partial.

Can anyone see why some pages aren't getting `@current_order` as designated in the `application_controller`?

Answer (score 0):

In your order-related controller(s) you probably have another `before_action` named `set_order` - and that'll overwrite the one in `ApplicationController`.  Rename one of 'em.

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly the issue!  I changed the one in the `application_controller` to `set_current_order` and it worked right away.